# Reverse polarity protection for parallel connection of 18650 batteries

Tags: batteries, reverse-polarity, 18650

I want to use two Li-Ion 18650 batteries in the device. The batteries need to be connected in parallel and they can be removed from the device (holder).

The device itself is protected from incorrect battery polarity, but I also want to protect the batteries themselves. If, when replacing the battery, at least one of the batteries is switched on with the wrong polarity, a short circuit will occur and a large current will flow, which can lead to heating, fire, failure, etc.

I had 2 ideas (but I would like to implement on MOSFET transistors):

1. Connect the diode in series, but then there will be a voltage drop of 0.4 volts, which is quite a lot. You cannot use an alarm system. And there will be no alignment.
2. Connect a parallel diode to each battery using a fuse. Then I can implement the alarm.

I found a reverse polarity protection circuit on a MOSFET transistor, but only for one element (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdBdf.png).

How can a similar scheme be applied to each battery?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that mostfet-based circuit does not really work if the output side can be powered, and that's exactly what's happening when you have multiple parallel devices.

There are ICs called "ideal diodes", like https://www.ti.com/product/LM66100 - which handles up to 1.5 amp, and has 0.1 ohm resistance (that's 0.1v voltage drop @ 1A and less at smaller currents). Note those are diodes, so they are not going to work if your device has integrated battery charger.

But for your specific application, two regular fuses (one per battery) are probably going to be the easiest. They will make sure that if one battery is inserted incorrectly, it's swiftly disconnected before any damage is done.